# Отвезти автомобиль в авторазборку или на авторазборку?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Отвезти автомобиль в авторазборку или на авторазборку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"В авторазборку" значит "в авторазборочную мастерскую".

"На авторазборку" значит "на процедуру авторазборки".